# Math function in VRT

Tags: qgis, excel, vrt

I am using the following VRT to load a Excel sheet into QGIS and I would like to perform some functions on the inputs to create new fields. Is this possible?

Ideally I would do pythagoras Field 10 and Field 11 to create a new field. It is not practical to do this in the original file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="Comparison-Data">
<SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">Comparison.xlsx</SrcDataSource>
<!--Header=False-->
<SrcSql dialect="sqlite">SELECT * FROM 'Data' LIMIT 60 OFFSET 5</SrcSql>
<Field name="Line" src="Field1" type="String"/>
<Field name="Point" src="Field3" type="String"/>
<Field name="1_Easting" src="Field4" type="String"/>
<Field name="1_Northing" src="Field5" type="String"/>
<Field name="2_Easting" src="Field6" type="String"/>
<Field name="2_Northing" src="Field7" type="String"/>
<Field name="Height" src="Field8" type="String"/>
<Field name="Delta_XLine" src="Field10" type="String"/>
<Field name="Delta_ILine" src="Field11" type="String"/>
<GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
<GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Field4" y="Field5"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Comment: Virtual format is documented http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html. Is your mathematics something that is supported by core SQLite SQL or by SpatiaLite math functions http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#math?

Comment: Yes I would use something like Pow( Pow(1_Easting - 2_Easting, 2)+Pow(1_Northing - 2_Northing,2),0.5)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use sql syntax of calculated field like

```
SELECT *, sqrt(power(1_Easting - 2_Easting, 2)+power(1_Northing - 2_Northing,2)) AS CalcDELTA FROM 'Data' LIMIT 60 OFFSET 5
```

But you'd probably need to install math extensions for sqllite https://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25

then compile it and load into sqllite like

```
$ gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.so
$ sqlite3 :memory:
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('./libsqlitefunctions.so');

sqlite> select sqrt(16);
4.0
sqlite>
```